# countdown clock for evey 20 min

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hey I need to set up a countdown on my website that count's backward to the next 0,20 or 40 min of each hour.
I mean that if the time for example is  08:14:20 it will print that there is 5 min and 40 sec left.
if the time is 11:37:05 then it'll print 2 min and 55 sec.

I dont want to do it by only counting down from 20 each time, because I need it to bt set up with the server time perfectly.

I'm not asking you to make it for me. only for and idea of how to make it.

Thank you!

Comment: And if the time is 10:41, should it show nineteen minutes (time until 11:00) or thirty-nine minutes (time until 11:20); is this local time or UTC time? And if you don't want us to do it for you, you'll need to show how far you've got, and where you're stuck.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/vFZhz/ and [.setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval)

Answer (score 2):

```
       // Create and start timer firing after 20 minute
       $w1 = new EvTimer(1200, 0, function () {
       echo "20 minute elapsed\n";
       });
       This Function is called after 20 minute
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get components of the current time like this:

```
var now = new Date();
var mins = now.getMinutes();
var secs = now.getSeconds();
```

Then you could run something like this:

```
if (mins >= 0 && mins<20) {
    var target = new Date(now.getTime() + (19-mins)*60 + (60-secs));
}
if (mins >= 20 && mins<40) {
    var target = new Date(now.getTime() + (39-mins)*60 + (60-secs));
}
if (mins >= 40 && mins<60) {
    var target = new Date(now.getTime() + (59-mins)*60 + (60-secs));
}

var secondsRemaining = target.getTime() - now.getTime();
```

`secondsRemaining` now contains the number of seconds until the next 20 minute milestone.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/xbUjN/

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you start with the Moment.js library

http://momentjs.com/

In fact, my experience with the library tells me it has everything you'll need.